# For-each loop variable holds value outside of ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx

I have an `ObservableList<String>`, a `ListView` to hold it and an event to update the selected items to a `Label`.

```
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "China", "Japan", "Korea", "India");
ListView<String> lvCountries = new ListView<>();
lvCountries.setItems(items);
lvCountries.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

lvCountries.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(observable -> {
    ObservableList<Integer> indices = lvCountries.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
    if (indices.size() != 0) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Selected items are");
        indices.forEach(index -> stringBuilder.append(" " + items.get(index)));
        lblSelected.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
});
```

Everything looks fine, but when I click randomly in high speed, sometimes it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the `index` holds a value of `-1`. Again, this only happens *sometimes* when I click randomly quickly between items in MULTIPLE mode of the `ListView`.

I'm not sure if it had something to do with the `ObservableList` or how the for-each loop works or the indices. The program doesn't crash or anything, but I would like to understand why and how this happens and the solution for it.

I'm using Java 8 update 181 (build 1.8.0_181-b13), IntelliJ IDEA CE, MacOS 10.14

Comment: there had been/are some bugs around the content of selectedIndices - some had been fixed, some not. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and add your fx version, so we can decide where the issue is located (your code or core fx, both possible :)

Comment: @Matt  As I said, it only happens sometimes when I click randomly at high speed. Oh, did I forget to mention that it's in MULTIPLE choice mode? Will update right away.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce the issue. It happens when you shift-select multiple elements, and then select one. In that case, the indices list contains -1.

For some strange reason (probably due to a bug as kleopatra noted), if you traverse the indices list twice, the second time it shows the correct index. Still looking into it.

Comment: hmm ... where is my comment from earlier today? Or did I forget to actually post it? So again: there's a gross usage error in the code snippet - listener code __must not__ access sibling properties, at least not those which are not completely orthogonal to each other! The state of the sibling at the time of receiving a change notification is unspecified.

Comment: @kleopatra I see, so the problem lies in my wrong usage code. Should I edit the whole question, including the title, to make it clear on my actual case, or should I delete this and post a new one asking for correct usage?